# SQL Server 2012, Concat a Date with a Time column to insert into a DateTime column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

In SQL Server 2012 ... I have two column in a table, 
TransactionDate(date,null) and 
TransactionTime(time, null)

I need to concatenate them together to insert into another table's column which is a Datetime datatype.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you come up with first.

Comment: Can you be more explicit with the data types of each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      TransactionDate DATE
    , TransactionTime TIME
)

INSERT INTO @temp (TransactionDate, TransactionTime)
VALUES 
    ('2013-04-27', '08:37:01.217'),
    ('2013-04-27', '12:39:14.613')

--INSERT INTO ... (DatetimeColumn)
SELECT CAST(TransactionDate AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(TransactionTime AS VARCHAR(12))
FROM @temp
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
SELECT TransactionDate+ CAST(TransactionTime AS datetime)
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dateadd(millisecond, datediff(millisecond, '00:00', TransactionTime), cast(TransactionDate as datetime))
```

Calculate the number of milliseconds since midnight for the time value and add that to your date value.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best place to start is the SQL Server online guide to date and time datatypes / functions: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

You should be able to use the [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function combined with [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213233.aspx) function to achieve this.